# Its possible to make action after ngIf?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-ng-if

i have an ngIf Nested in two ngFor's, to make a ion-list, but i dont want duplocated ion-list, is there a way to make that if the ngIf is correct then it changes a variable value like Show=false, so it doesnt keep making ion-lists? thanks

here is the code, the one with *** is the one i would like that when it fires it changes the second value required hall.show to True, so it doesn't repeat

```
<ion-content padding>
  <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="listaRdy">
      <template ngFor let-hall [ngForOf]="pasillosObj">
        ***<ion-list *ngIf="item.pasillo==hall.value && hall.show ==false">
          <ion-list-header>{{hall.name}}</ion-list-header>
          <template ngFor let-articulo [ngForOf]="listaRdy">
            <ion-item *ngIf="articulo.pasillo==hall.value">{{articulo.name}}</ion-item>
          </template>
        </ion-list>
      </template>
  </template>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please add some code showing what you have tried, what it gives you, and what you would like to get instead.

Comment: @Duncan i just did, sorry if i wants clear enough

Answer (score 1):

How about you call a function from your template? I would try this:

```
***<ion-list *ngIf="item.pasillo==hall.value && hall.show ==false">
{{setToTrue(hall.show)}}
...
```

And then in your `.ts` file:

```
 setToTrue(variable){
       variable = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i've been looking for, i hope it works! thanks in advance

Comment: is not working, i just noticed that this solution doesnt change the attribute value in the object array, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realise that with Angular your template isn't just rendered once, it will re-render whenever any of the expressions change.

That means if you do change `hall.show` as a side effect of rendering the template Angular will immediately render it again, and again and again until either it stops changing or until Angular gives up and you get an error logged in the console.

That means there is no way to do what you are trying to achieve, you cannot update the state of an element as you are iterating through it with ngFor and expect a predictable result.

Instead what you need to do is to iterate through the data structure in the Typescript code and precompute all of the values you need so that you can render the template cleanly. You may need to change the way you structure the data: for example instead of storing a boolean flag to indicate whether where or not you already used a particular `hall` value, store a reference to the value that you want to use instead. Or, better, split the single `pasillosObj` list into separate lists stored attached to the `item` elements, that way you don't need the `ngIf` at all:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="listaRdy">
      <template ngFor let-hall [ngForOf]="item.pasillosObj">
       <ion-list>
          <ion-list-header>{{hall.name}}</ion-list-header>
          <template ngFor let-articulo [ngForOf]="listaRdy">
            <ion-item *ngIf="articulo.pasillo==hall.value">{{articulo.name}}</ion-item>
          </template>
        </ion-list>
      </template>
  </template>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a javascript function in your ng-if statement, such as:

```
$scope.myNgIf=function(params){//Show=false or whatever; //return true of false;}
```

and then in your HTML `<div ... ng-if="myNgIf()">my content</div>`

Comment: can you show me how to perform that in the code i just uploaded, and sorry for not having the code from the begining

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you were using Angular 2. In your Angular class file define your desired function like  myNgIf(): boolean {//your code; //return true/false;} and in your html code <ion-list *ngIf="myNgIf()" ....